# Some line borders are thicker than the others line

Tags: html, css

I am creating a calendar application. I created a bunch of boxes to hold the dates. But the problem is, some line borders get darker or bolder or thicker than the others. Please see my css and html below:

```
<style>
    section {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    }

    section > div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style> 

<section>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < numDummyColumns; i++)
                    {
                        <div></div>
                    }

                    @for (var i = 1; i <= _monthEnd.Day; i++)
                    {
                        var calendarItem = _calendarEntries.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Date == new DateTime(_year, _month, i));

                        <div>
                            <h2>@i</h2>
                            @if (calendarItem != null)
                            {
                                <p>@calendarItem.Title</p>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                </section>
```

[image]

Comment: I assume that only "internal" borders are thicker, am I right ? Would you please provide us the final html too ? :)

Comment: @Phillipe Yes only the internal borders Sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was a table we could use `border-collapse: collapse` to collapse borders for elements, since we're using div we have to collapse manually by ourselves.

It is because their borders are colliding with each to form a bolder border you could overcome this issue by setting margin `-1px` from both sides `left` and `top`.

```html
<style>
    section {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    }

    section > div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100px;
    }
  section > div + div {margin-left: -1px;}
  section > div:nth-child(7n+1) {margin-left: 0;}
  section > div:nth-child(n+8) {margin-top: -1px;}
</style> 

<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
</section>
```